# C# winforms converting a project to .dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I working on a group task, I must input my work into the main project as a .dll project. in other words I should replace the old InfoCard project with my edited InfoCard.
I have done all the edit and changes in a Winform project how I can convert it into .dll and add it to the main project, Thank you in advance

Comment: You could change the Project -> Property -> Output Type -> Class Library

Comment: Although this is really more of a work around, you can create a new project that is a library, and copy the entire project into it. When you build it the form can still be called just like usual, but it's a dll - or you can do what @Ian said, which is the same thing but without creating a new project

Comment: Just Change the Project output type to class library and reference that into your main project.

Comment: Ok, what should i do with the old/replaced dll project, just delete it ?

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer
Right click your Project name

- Click 'Build'
- Go to your project location (for example: C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\YourProjectName\bin\Debug); In Debug folder you can see the .dll format file
- Copy the .dll file and paste it into your current project folder
- In your main project, type:

  > using YourProjectName;